# Get local DNS settings in Python

Tags: python, dns, localhost, cross-platform, system

Is there any elegant and cross platform (Python) way to get the local DNS settings?

It could probably work with a complex combination of modules such as `platform` and `subprocess`, but maybe there is already a good module, such as `netifaces` which can retrieve it in low-level and save some "reinventing the wheel" effort.

Less ideally, one could probably query something like `dig`, but I find it "noisy", because it would run an extra request instead of just retrieving something which exists already locally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @MasterOfTheHouse.
I ended up writing my own function. It's not so elegant, but it does the job for now. There's plenty of room for improvement, but well...

```
import os
import subprocess

def get_dns_settings()->dict:
    # Initialize the output variables
    dns_ns, dns_search = [], ''

    # For Unix based OSs
    if os.path.isfile('/etc/resolv.conf'):
        for line in open('/etc/resolv.conf','r'):
            if line.strip().startswith('nameserver'):
                nameserver = line.split()[1].strip()
                dns_ns.append(nameserver)
            elif line.strip().startswith('search'):
                search = line.split()[1].strip()
                dns_search = search

    # If it is not a Unix based OS, try "the Windows way"
    elif os.name == 'nt':
        cmd = 'ipconfig /all'
        raw_ipconfig = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
        # Convert the bytes into a string
        ipconfig_str = raw_ipconfig.decode('cp850')
        # Convert the string into a list of lines
        ipconfig_lines = ipconfig_str.split('\n')

        for n in range(len(ipconfig_lines)):
            line = ipconfig_lines[n]
            # Parse nameserver in current line and next ones
            if line.strip().startswith('DNS-Server'):
                nameserver = ':'.join(line.split(':')[1:]).strip()
                dns_ns.append(nameserver)
                next_line = ipconfig_lines[n+1]
                # If there's too much blank at the beginning, assume we have
                # another nameserver on the next line
                if len(next_line) - len(next_line.strip()) > 10:
                    dns_ns.append(next_line.strip())
                    next_next_line = ipconfig_lines[n+2]
                    if len(next_next_line) - len(next_next_line.strip()) > 10:
                        dns_ns.append(next_next_line.strip())

            elif line.strip().startswith('DNS-Suffix'):
                dns_search = line.split(':')[1].strip()

    return {'nameservers': dns_ns, 'search': dns_search}

print(get_dns_settings())
```

By the way... how did you manage to write two answers with the same account?

Answer (score 0):

Using subprocess you could do something like this, in a MacBook or Linux system

```py
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['cat', '/etc/resolv.conf'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print(stdout, stderr)
```

or do something like this

```py
import subprocess
with open('dns.txt', 'w') as f:
    process = subprocess.Popen(['cat', '/etc/resolv.conf'], stdout=f)
```

The first output will go to stdout and the second to a file

Comment: Thanks! Sure... but this doesn't work on Windows :/ It would require calling something like `platform` and cover all operating system options with different methods. I am expecting something more "Pythonic".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will solve your problem

```py
import subprocess

def get_local_dns(cmd_):
    with open('dns1.txt', 'w+') as f:
        with open('dns_log1.txt', 'w+') as flog:
            try:
                process = subprocess.Popen(cmd_, stdout=f, stderr=flog)
            except FileNotFoundError as e:
                flog.write(f"Error while executing this command {str(e)}")


linux_cmd = ['cat', '/etc/resolv.conf']
windows_cmd = ['windows_command', 'parameters']
commands = [linux_cmd, windows_cmd]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for cmd in commands:
        get_local_dns(cmd)
```